# How to add bluetooth-serial to ionic app with out peer dependence warnings?

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3

When I install bluetooth-serial to Ionic app its always give peer dependence warning how to resolve those. I add screenshot below.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that you dont have all of the npm packages installed that you need to run `ionic-native/bluetooth-serial`.  To fix those warning (and let bt-serial run properly) make sure you install all of the peer dependencies listed:

```
npm install rxjs@^5.5.11
npm install @ionic-native/core@5.0.0-beta.21
npm install cordova-plugin-ionic@^5/0.0
```